# UI mock-up in PDF

Tags: pdf, user-interface, mockups

I want to do a mock-up GUI within a pdf file. Basically, it's a series of pages. If you click button A on a first page, for example, it goes to the third page, if you click button B, it goes to the second page, etc. I want to know if there is tutorial, video for this and what software should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Acrobat (not reader -- standard or professional), creating clickable links within PDFs is as simple as click and drag. E.g. as documented here:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/graphics_multimedia/3439118.htm

"You need the full Standard version of Acrobat or better, go to tools->Advanced Editing->Link tool. Draw a rectangle around the text to link and it will prompt you for link options (in-document, web URL, link colors, etc.)"

Answer (score 0):

The pdf requirement is an odd one and will make this difficult. If you are just looking for a mockup GUI there are better ways to do it!
Here's a free one:
http://www.10screens.com/

Here is a popular one:
http://www.balsamiq.com/

And here is a previous question on this that you might find useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156755/tools-for-creating-a-user-interface-prototype

Good luck!

Comment: Delivering stuff in PDF format has enormous advantages. Almost everyone can view them, they work offline, and you don't have to worry about browser versions. The fact that there are incredibly good workflows to PDF from tools like Illustrator and Photoshop doesn't hurt either. A lot of wireframes in the real world are developed using the Adobe toolchain and delivered as PDF -- being able to make them clickable is pretty damn nice.

Answer (score 0):

Create your GUI mockups with [MockupUI](http://mockupui.com) and export the designs to a PDF document, one screen per page. Then you can open it in Acrobat and add page links.